# Is 15 amp circuit sufficient for 14.8 amp load?

Tags: electrical

I have an 8.1amp garbage disposal and a 6.7amp drinking water filter system under a sink - both 110V. Is one 15 amp circuit sufficient?

Comment: How often are they run, and how long do they run for?

Comment: Disposal is run as needed - guessing 5 times per day, < 5 seconds each time. The filtering system is only on when hot water is dispensed - so probably the same frequency

Comment: Are they cord-and-plug-connected or hardwired? Also, this is in North America, right?

Comment: Both plugs, located in US

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your 15A circuit will be fine, considering that both loads are noncontinuous loads and they are plugged into different receptacles (210.19(A)(1)/210.20(A).  The NEC treats the two receptacles in a duplex receptacle device as separate receptacles, by the way -- this means that you don't have to worry about the 12A limit on a single receptacle load on a 15A circuit (210.21(B)(2)).

Comment: Thank you. To clarify - the devices are sharing a duplex receptacle. So each device has an own plug, and they fill up one of these: http://www.cooperindustries.com/content/public/en/wiring_devices/products/receptacles/residential/general_duty/standard_duplex_receptacles_270.html Does that change your answer? (not sure on terminology of outlet vs receptacle)

Comment: @Nikita -- no, I already addressed the case where both receptacles are on the same device yoke in my answer :)